# Get list of "n" unique random numbers from the given range

Tags: python

I need 3 unique random numbers between 1 to 20.

I have a loop generating 3 random numbers from 1-20. And I don't want there to be any repeats. I have something that works for the first two numbers. But in my code the first and third numbers can still be the same which needs to be fixed.

```
i = 1

while i <= 3:
    x = random.randint(1, 20)
    print(choice([i for i in range(1, 20) if i != [x]]))
    i += 1
```

Is there a better way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: What about randomly sorting list made of `range(1, 20)` and then take the first 3 numbers?

Comment: If you want to pick from such a small range, you can afford to create a list of all numbers, perform a random shuffle and pick the first three numbers.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I will delete my comment because it should not be anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). Below example will return you 3 unique random numbers between 1 to 20.

```
>>> import random

>>> sample_count = 3   # count of required unique numbers
>>> start_range, end_range = 1, 20  # start and end range

>>> random.sample(range(start_range, end_range+1), sample_count)
[4, 1, 14]
```

Please refer [random.sample() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) for more details.